# iOS Change Width of UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, width

In my custom `UITableViewCell` I have a `UIButton`. For a particular cell (row) object I want to change the `width` of the button. I tried many ways, but can't change the size of button in any ways. I am not using `AutoLayout` in this cell, as this button contains text and image and using auto layout am not able to set the spacing between text ands image properly.

Code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that initiates cell and calls resize function :

```
    } else if ([text isEqualToString:@"Now"] ) {    //(indexPath.row == 2) {
    vcell.listDataSource = inList;
    count = inList.count;
    vcell.listsTableView.tag = 2;
    [vcell reSizeButton];
```

Method in custom UITableViewCell :

```
-(void) reSizeButton {
CGRect btnFrame = self.button.frame;
btnFrame.size = CGSizeMake(157.0, btnFrame.size.height);
[self.button setFrame:btnFrame];

//[self.button sizeToFit];
//[self.button setNeedsDisplay];
[self.button setNeedsLayout];

return;
}
```

Method is being called properly. As it is being called during initing cell properties, so I don't think I need to call to reload the cell.

**UPDATE :**

After calling the reSizeButton method, I am calling the setText method :-

```
-(void) setButtonText :(NSString *) text withCount:(int)count isExpanded:(BOOL)expanded {
titleText = text;
countNums = count;
cellExpanded = expanded;

[self updateButtonText];

return;
}

-(void) updateButtonText {
countNums = (int)[self.listDataSource count];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d) ", titleText, countNums ];

[self.button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:12.0] ];
[self.button setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[self.button sizeToFit];
[self.button setNeedsLayout];

return;

}
```

Maybe his be causing the problem....

Can you point where am I going wrong ? Since long am trying with this, but couldn't solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure button already exists at the point you are doing this ? Check if self.button is != nil, maybe you create button later ?
For frame operations no special additional calls are required.

Comment: change Button frame directly on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `if` condition

Comment: Oh ya, button is a member in my cell object and is linked to the button in the nib file. @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

Comment: Are you sure it is linked properly ?

Comment: sizeToFit may kill your frame settings, but if it's commmented it should be fine.

Comment: I have commented that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Greg and @Grzegorz Krukowski . Thanks for your time and effort to help me.

Don't know what was the problem, but I again un-checked (which was already unchecked) AutoLayout checkbox from xib for the cell. Tried again. My Code remains same as shown in question. And it started to work as expected.

Godness, can't recognize the problem and solved the issue.